# Type string memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct InsanFactory.User storage ref

Tags: solidity, addresses, arrays, mapping, struct

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.7.0;

contract InsanFactory{

    struct User{
         string name;
         address myaddress;
    }

    mapping(address => User) public userStructs;

    address[] public userAddress ;

    function createUser(string memory name,address myaddress) public{
        userStructs[msg.sender] = name;
        //set user name
        userStructs[msg.sender] = myaddress;
        //address'i degistirdim
        userAddress.push(msg.sender);

    }
    function getResult() external view returns(address[] memory){
        return userAddress;
    }
}
```

When I compile this code I got 2 errors:

First error at line 15 says:

```
Type string memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct InsanFactory.User storage ref.
line 15(userStructs[msg.sender] = name;)
```

Second one at line 17 says:

```
Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct InsanFactory.User storage ref.
line 17(userStructs[msg.sender] = name;)
```

What should I do for my error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to directly access the members of the struct. [Solidity docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#structs).

```
userStructs[msg.sender].name = name;

userStructs[msg.sender].myaddress = myaddress;
```

Code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.7.0;

contract InsanFactory{
    struct User{
        string name;
        address myaddress;
    }
    mapping(address => User) public userStructs;
    address[] public userAddress ;

    function createUser(string memory name,address myaddress) public{
        userStructs[msg.sender].name = name;
        //set user name
        userStructs[msg.sender].myaddress = myaddress;
        //address'i degistirdim
        userAddress.push(msg.sender);
    }
    function getResult() external view returns(address[] memory){
        return userAddress;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mapping requires a key of address type to value of User type. name is of string memory type and cannot be implicitly converted to User type. Here's a quick fix:

```
userStructs[msg.sender] = User(name, myaddress);
```

Code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.7.0;

contract InsanFactory{

    struct User{
         string name;
         address myaddress;
    }

    mapping(address => User) public userStructs;

    address[] public userAddress ;

    function createUser(string memory name,address myaddress) public{
//map address type to User type
        userStructs[msg.sender] = User(name, myaddress);
        userAddress.push(msg.sender);

    }
    function getResult() external view returns(address[] memory){
        return userAddress;
    }
}
```